# How to omit some results from it.combinations() in the while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, combinations, python-itertools

Here is a fragment of the code that creates a certain graph:

```
           h=0
           while len(added)<i+1:   

                 g.add_node(z1+h*2)
                 g.add_node(z2+h*2)

                 good.append(z1+h*2)
                 good.append(z2+h*2)

                 for u in it.combinations(good, 8):
                     u1 = list(u)

                    # the rest of the code...

           h=h+1
```

Where:

`good=[]` - list with current values in the form of natural numbers [0,1,2,3,4,5,...].

`z1, z2` - the largest even and odd numbers from the current values in the `good=[]` list.

The while loop is executed until a condition is met at the edges of the graph. However, in each subsequent step of the while loop, subsequent even and odd numbers are added to satisfy the condition.

The problem is that after adding the even and odd numbers, the function `it.combinations()` checks all combinations from the beginning, including those that have already been checked. What unnecessarily extends the operation of the loop.
However, I would like the next steps of the `while` loop to use only those combinations that contain the newly added values`z1 + h*2` and `z2 + h*2`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remember result of `it.combinations` in each step and in next step iterate only on complement (difference) of these current and previous results in your `for` loop. I would suggest using operations on sets to count complement quickly.

```
h=0
previous_combinations = set()
while len(added)<i+1:   

    g.add_node(z1+h*2)
    g.add_node(z2+h*2)

    good.append(z1+h*2)
    good.append(z2+h*2)

    current_combinations = set(it.combinations(good, 8))

    for u in current_combinations - previous_combinations:
        u1 = list(u)
        # the rest of the code...
        h=h+1

    previous_combinations = current_combinations
```

Comment: I was just afraid to remembering the results of `it.combinations` and I wanted to avoid it. in my case, this solution works slower than checking all results from the beginning. Although the solution is generally correct :)

Comment: I think I will have to think about the implementation of parallel calculations.

Comment: Probably your `good` list is quite long, so it.combinations is even longer. Making set from that iterator and then counting complement with previouus one takes long time. It's not because of remembering result, but because of iterating over it to many times. I believe what you could do is to implement your own version of `it.combinations` (still remembering previous results to get rid of them).

Comment: As a start point take a look at existing itertools.combinations implementation in [c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c) and it's [python equivalent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).